# What is "Triangulable Triad"?

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, homotopy-theory, triangulation

I am reading George W. Whitehead's Homotopy Theory; Corollary 1.0.2 mentioned the term "Triangulable triad" without definition. May I know how it is defined?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't "triangulable triad"? A triad is a triple $(X, A, B)$ of spaces with some inclusion relation between them, although I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, yes, you are right! It has been corrected. But I am still curious how it is defined...

Comment: Probably a triad that can be triangulated, i.e. there exist simplicial complex structures on $A,B,X$.